# Incompatibility between Jquery 2 div [hide-show]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My second `<div>` is shown when page is refreshed and I want to avoid this.

```js
$(function(){
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").hide()
        $("#div2").fadeIn(1000)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus sequi omnis veritatis dicta laborum iste provident, ex ratione, neque veniam quis. Hic repellat nulla in minus! Sit quia dicta modi.
    <button id="button">Click</button>
    
  </div>
    
    
  <div id="div2">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus sequi omnis veritatis dicta laborum iste provident, ex ratione, neque veniam quis. Hic repellat nulla in minus! Sit quia dicta modi.
</div>
```

Comment: why do you hide #div2 by js and not with css and just fade it in if you need it ?

Comment: Because, I love using Jquery :)

Comment: Put JS code inside the html/css/js snippet, also fixed grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding `div2` by `hide()` function use css for it.

```
#div2 { display:none; }
```

and change your script code missing `;` in code

```
 <script>
$(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div2").fadeIn(1000);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Accept and upvote if it helps you. Welcome glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!doctype html>
 <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>
       $(function()
       {
         $("#div2").hide();
         $("button").click(function(){
         $("#div1").hide()
         $("#div2").fadeIn(1000)
        });

        });
        </script>
 </head>

 <div id="div1">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus sequi omnis veritatis dicta laborum iste provident, ex ratione, neque veniam quis. Hic repellat nulla in minus! Sit quia dicta modi.
    <button id="button">Click</button>
 </div>

 <div id="div2">
   Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus sequi omnis veritatis dicta laborum iste provident, ex ratione, neque veniam quis. Hic repellat nulla in minus! Sit quia dicta modi.
 </div>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you only need jquery to run your code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div2").fadeIn(1000);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus sequi omnis veritatis dicta laborum iste provident, ex ratione, neque veniam quis. Hic repellat nulla in minus! Sit quia dicta modi.
   
    
  </div>
     <button id="button">Click</button>
    
  <div id="div2">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus sequi omnis veritatis dicta laborum iste provident, ex ratione, neque veniam quis. Hic repellat nulla in minus! Sit quia dicta modi.
</div>
```